# recordVarSet issue

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, account, button-overrides

I am overriding the LIST button of account Home page with my own visual force page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"
           recordSetVar="accounts"
           tabStyle="Account"
           sidebar="false">

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="a">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!a.name}">
                <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" subject="{!a.Id}"/>
                <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" subject="{!a.Id}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>      
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

In account home page from Picklist, I select All Accounts, then click GO.
so the literal meaning of this is it should display all account records.
But its not displaying all records only a few.

Is my understanding right or is there something in code that needs to be done?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you expecting more than 10000 records? No more than 10,000 records can be returned by a standard list controller. Custom controllers can work with larger results sets.

Comment: Hi, Yes in fact if there are 10000 records it show all the records . But here in my case i have about 5000 records but its not even showing 1/3rd of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page automatically uses the standard list controller that defaults to using pagination on the data as [Pagination with a List Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_pagination.htm) explains. So you will need to add a controller extension class that invokes [setPageSize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm#apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_setPageSize) (using a large number) on the StandardSetController.

**PS**

The extension class would look like this:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension {
     public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc) {
         ssc.setPageSize(1000);
     }
}
```

and is added to the page like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyExtension" ...
```

Comment: could u pls show how to add an extension code and set page size?

Comment: @KrishnaCasukhela Added example code.